# Why does this registration form ajax mysql insert work in chrome and safari but not firefox?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, browser

I am setting up a user registration page. It works in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox (latest Mac versions).  I am working locally on MAMP.

**Expected Output:**

- Ajax request is sent after submit button click.
- If username is available, user, password, email are inserted into mysql table.  Success:  hidden div "You are registered" appears.
- Else, hidden div "Username unavailable appears"

**Real Output:**

- Output is as expected in Chrome and Safari.
- In Firefox, nothing is inserted in the table.  No hidden divs show up, instead, the entire webpage reloads.

Why is the code below producing these different results?

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#registersubmit").click(function() {
        var dataString = $("#registerclick").serialize();

        if (registerclick.user.value == "")
        {
            $('.error').show();
            registerclick.user.focus();
            return (false);
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "register.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(reg) {
                    if (!reg)
                    {
                        $('.userexists').hide();
                        $('.error').hide();
                        $('.success').fadeOut(200).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.userexists').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP for MYSQL Insert**

```
$user = ($_POST['user']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$time = time();
$password = ($_POST['password']);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include("config.php");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email,timestamp) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '$time')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Assume that password encryption and mysql escape precautions have been made.

Comment: If #registersubmit is a submit button inside a form, you should use `event.preventDefault();` at the beginning of your function. So, the browser (Firefox) sends the form but it doesn't make the ajax request. Maybe on the other browsers you had lucky..

Comment: One good way to debug this is to add console.log() statements and click the "persist" button in firebug. Then see what is really going on.

Comment: @RPM I edited the code to reflect my injection precautions.

Comment: @Jose Adrian I tried event.preventDefault(); but there was no change in behavior.  I'm trying console.log, but no leads yet.

Comment: Like this? `...click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); /* the rest... */ });`

Comment: @JoseAdrian yes.  $(function() {
$("#registersubmit").click(function() {
event.preventDefault(); /*the rest*/

Comment: You have forgotten something. Event should be a parameter. On Firefox event is not recognized, so you should pass it. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Feqz3/1/

Comment: @JoseAdrian ohhhh. I overlooked your comment about a missing parameter.  so now the code reads: ...$(function(){$("#registersubmit").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();...  After I run the code now, Firebug says, "registerclick is not defined".  I don't know what to do after this.    Thanks again for all of the help.

Comment: @JoseAdrian you indirectly helped me find the answer!!!  the problem was with ...if (registerclick.user.value == "")... Firefox apparently can't handle this.  So i replaced it with if (document.registerclick.user.value.length == "")...and it now works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I though that registerclick was some kind of object ( `registerclick = { user: { value: '' } }` ). Haha! Well... Keep coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with

```
if (registerclick.user.value == "")
```

Firefox apparently can't handle this for reasons I don't know. So I replaced it with

```
if (document.registerclick.user.value.length == "")
```

and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Since problems lies in client part only, you need to inspect client code.
Install firebug for firefox and debug what is broken in FF.

I may give you one idea just from the top of my head, though. In latest Firefoxes (from 7<sup>th</sup> or 8<sup>th</sup> version) elements with some `id` are not automatically exposed into global variables with the same name.

I bet, you didn't declared `registerclick` variable by yourself.

Therefore you need either to declare this variable:

```
var registerclick = $('#registerclick').get(0);
```

or replace `registerclick` in your code with `forms.registerclick` or somewhat... anyway, I hope, you get the idea.

PS: He-he, read comments. Anyway, I'll leave my answer.